# Get current element from a service (cycle Hook problems)

Tags: angular, service, lifecycle

Hello i have some troubles with angular cycle hook.

**this is the Stackblitz of my test:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpoyqm

**This is the logic:**

I have two components and 1 service for store data

1) billings.component

2) billing.component

In billings.component i have a method **setCurrentBilling** for sent the current billing to the service and show the billing (ngIF).

In billing.component i need to get this current component from the service. if i try to console it in the ngOnInit, the property **current** is undefined the first time.

what is the step for get the current billing at the first click please ?

Thank you for your precious help

Comment: You should add your code here, even if it cannot be executed, because you could delete your stackblitz project in any moment and this question will became useless

Answer (score 1):

Your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let billingItem of billings" class="LG_invoice-item" #billing (click)="setCurrentBilling(billingItem)" >
  <div class="LG_form-title" (click)="billing.value = !billing.value">
    {{billingItem.month}} {{billingItem.years}}
  </div>
  <app-billing *ngIf="billing.value" ></app-billing>
</div>
```

So you have a parent `div` and a nested one, both with a click listener.

The first one to be executed is the inner one:

```
(click)="billing.value = !billing.value"
```

Which makes the template to be re-rendered, showing now a new element:

```
<app-billing *ngIf="billing.value" ></app-billing>
```

So the ngOnInit of this element is executed:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.billingsService.log(); 
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.billingsService.log(); 
      }, 0);
    
    //console.log('currentelem: ', );
  }
```

Here you still haven't set `current`. And then, after this first cycle is completed, the other click handler comes into action:

```
(click)="setCurrentBilling(billingItem)"
```

And after that, the `setTimeout` from the first `click` will be resolved.

#### Solution: a click handler could do both tasks:

```
<div *ngFor="let billingItem of billings" class="LG_invoice-item" #billing 
    (click)="billing.value = !billing.value;setCurrentBilling(billingItem)" >
  <div class="LG_form-title">
    {{billingItem.month}} {{billingItem.years}}
  </div>
  <app-billing *ngIf="billing.value" ></app-billing>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a way for make the same without the settimeout?

Comment: @orphen92300 no, it's not possible with your current approach. Because, to update the `current` of service, the browser's javascript engine needs at-least a tick (some time). `setTimeout` helps to wait for a tick and after that your current is updated. You can read more about that here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#abide-by-the-unidirectional-data-flow-rule. If you want to change the approach, you can use Observable, that would work fine without `setTimeout`

Comment: I think with my solution there is no need to use setTimeout